# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using redux toolkit and doing API call. However I am getting the error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
at SignUpForm.otpEmailCallBack (signUp.jsx:215)
at api.js:50

```
otpEmailCallBack = (res) => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
      toast(<AlertSuccess message={res.data.otp} />);
      this.props.updateStep(null, 4);
      this.props.updateVerifyEmail({
        otp: res.data.otp,
        email: this.state.data.email,
        code: res.data.code,
      });
    } else {
      toast(<AlertError message={res.data.error} />);
    }
  };
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show how `otpEmailCallBack` is being used

Comment: It is called inside emailCallback @ShubhamKhatri:   
emailCallback = (res) => {
    console.log(res)
    if (res.status === 200) {
      const emailParams = { email: this.state.data.email };
      this.props.sendEmailOtp(emailParams, this.otpEmailCallBack);
    } else {
      this.setState({
        loader: false,
        btnClass: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block",
      });
      toast(<AlertError message={res.data.error} />);
    }
  };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the res from api to `otpEmailCallback` which is why it receives the values as undefined when it is being called. To handle that you can bind the response to the function when you are passing it as callback to `sendEmailOtp` function

```js
emailCallback = (res) => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
        const emailParams = {
          email: this.state.data.email
        };
        this.props.sendEmailOtp(emailParams, this.otpEmailCallBack.bind(this, res));
    } else {
        this.setState({
          loader: false,
          btnClass: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block",
        });
        toast( < AlertError message = {
              res.data.error
            }
            />);
     } 
 };
```

Comment: Glad to have helped. Consider marking the answer as accepted